# How to read information about file allocation table of USB mass storage device?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32

How do I read the file allocation table of a USB mass storage device, which has been formatted using [FAT32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#FAT32) file system (functions, structs)?

I'm trying to do this in Linux.

Comment: There's never any need to do this yourself / by hand in linux - just mount the mass storage device as `vfat` filesystem and access it through normal filesystem I/O. The functionality is already there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to *[Understanding FAT32 Filesystems](http://www.pjrc.com/tech/8051/ide/fat32.html)*.

Comment: ... and if you google "fatgen103.pdf" you'll find Microsoft's specification document itself.